# Cast custom struct to another template type

Tags: c++, templates, casting

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Colordata
{
public:
    T *data;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long length;

    template <size_t N>
    Colordata(T (&arr)[N])
    {
        length = N;
        size = sizeof(arr);
        T dataArr[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            dataArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        data = dataArr;
    }
    template <typename TCast>
    operator TCast() const
    {
        TCast dataCastTmp[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            dataCastTmp[i] = (TCast)data[i];
        }
        return Colordata<TCast>(dataCastTmp);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = {12, 434, 54};
    auto a = Colordata<int>(arr);
    auto b = (float)a;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to convert `Struct<typename>` to `Struct<another typename>` another typename doesn't exist. I think so 'cos I get error in the compiler log:

> no matching function for call to «Colordata::Colordata(float [((const Colordata*)this)->Colordata::length])»

Is there any way to casting template struct to template struct?

Comment: You're trying to cast it to `float`, not to `Colordata<float>`.

Comment: @Thomas I also tried to use `Colordata<TCast> convert()` (without operator). Same error.

Comment: Also your CTOR requires the length to be a compile time constant. So your cast won't work as the CTOR of `Colordata<float>` can't be called with `length` as `N`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vGWsrdGMd

Comment: @SimonKraemer it works without length (dynamic array). But how can I set up the constructor to get length using static array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with this code, but the one you asked about is happening because of the signature of the conversion operator:

```
    template <typename TCast>
    operator TCast() const
```

If you try to cast to a `Colordata<float>` then `TCast` will be the type `Colordata<float>`, and not `float` as the implementation assumes.

The solution is to only allow conversions to other `Colordata` instantiations:

```
    template <typename TCast>
    operator Colordata<TCast>() const
```

Now `TCast` will be `float` as desired, and you're one step closer to correct code.

---

The other problems are the use of variable-length arrays (not supported in C++), and storing pointers to local variables that outlive their scope leading to undefined behaviour. Use `std::vector` to make life easier and safer.

Comment: I have a question. Before I used D. In D static arrays of int [3] is int*3, but dynamic array is a buffer like {int, int, int ... outOfBuffer}. And dynamic array requires bigger memory than a static array. As I read vector is just a c++ alternative to a dynamic array. Is vector also requires bigger memory than int*3?

Comment: Yes, a `std::vector` contains a pointer to the actual data, a `size_t` for the length, and a `size_t` for the capacity. If you know the length at compile time, take a look at `std::array` (but plain arrays could work as well in that case).

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. Will try vectors